# Optuna Median Pruner n_warmup_steps

Tags: xgboost, hyperparameter-tuning, lightgbm, pruning

For Gradient Boosting Models such as XGBOOST and LGBM does n_warmup_steps in optuna.pruners.MedianPruner refer to the minimum number of folds evaluated before pruning is triggered?

I.e. if number of CV folds equals 5 then n_warmup_steps=1 means pruning only takes place after at least one 2/5 folds is evaluated (since it starts counting at 0)?

Answer (score 4):

The `steps` in `n_warmup_steps` refer to the incremental steps taken during *gradient decent*. So with `n_warmup_steps=1` the trial will directly check the loss for the very first incremental step. To put it differently, with `n_warmup_steps=1` a trial has to achieve a good result immediatly after the gradient decent started. 
As you are using `optuna.pruners.MedianPruner` following applies (copied from the [official documentation](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/optuna.pruners.MedianPruner.html)):

> Prune if the trial’s best intermediate result is worse than median of
> intermediate results of previous trials at the same step.

So if a trial does not yield a better result (measured via the objective/loss function) than the median of the intermediate results at the same step, it will be pruned. 
The parameter `n_warmup_steps` can be used in conjunction with `n_startup_trials` in order to get a robust median value first - so numbers of trials without pruning. After `n_startup_trials`, the trials will be pruned after `n_warmup_steps` if they performed worse than the preceding trials after the same amount of steps while gradient decending.

The rationale behind the parameter `n_warmup_steps` ist that a trial can start with a loss value below the median, but can give a much better loss value eventually - after more iterations (e.g. depending on the learning rate [...]).

It's not easy for me to explain it, maybe the images at the beginning of this [article](https://tech.preferred.jp/en/blog/how-we-implement-hyperband-in-optuna/) give a better intuition.